# Unorthodox tricks for explaining that this mixed model $SSE$ is proportional to a chisquare

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, chi-squared-distribution

I usually deal with problems like these easily, but this time, I am stuck. I've pulled out every trick for showing chisquare distribution that I can think of, but nothing worked. You will soon see the problem. We are in a linear mixed effect model setting. Suppose $Y_{ij} = \mu + A_i + \varepsilon_{ij}$, such that $A_i \sim N(0,\sigma_A^2)$ for all $i$, $i = 1,\cdots,I$ and $\varepsilon_{ij} \stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(0,\sigma^2)$, $1 \leq j \leq J$. $A_i, \varepsilon_{ij}$ are all independent for all combinations of $A_i, \varepsilon_{ij}$ and all $i,j$. I want to explain why

$$
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^I\sum_{j=1}^J (Y_{ij}- \overline Y_ {i \cdot})^2 \sim \chi^2_\nu,
$$
for some $\nu$ where $\overline Y_ {i \cdot}$ denotes the mean across all $j$ for fixed $i$. Clearly $Y_{ij}$s are not not independent for fixed $i$ (right?). This is the problem causing all my normal tricks to fail. Can you suggest some new tricks that I may need to add to my bag of tricks for dealing with this?

Comment: Hint: Fix $I$ and $j$ and write out explicitly what $(Y_{ij}- \overline Y_ {i \cdot})$ is (that is, expand that $\overline Y_ {i \cdot})$ term completely), and then decide whether it depends on $A_i$ (or on $\mu$ for that matter) at all. If not, then $\sum_{j=1}^J (Y_{ij}- \overline Y_ {i \cdot})$ is essentially like a $\sum_{j=1}^J (X_i-\bar{X})^2$ where the $X_i$ are independent $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables, isn't it? So, that inner sum is essentially a scaled $\chi^2$ random variable, and the outer sum is the sum of $I$ independent scaled $\chi^2$ random variables. Just the usual tricks

Comment: If you want to copy and paste this into a reply, I will accept it as the final answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Fix the numerical values of $i$ and $j$ and write out *explicitly* what $Y_{ij}- \overline Y_ {i \cdot}$ is, expanding out that second term as the sum of $J$ different terms etc. Then, figure out whether the
quantity $(Y_{ij}- \overline Y_ {i \cdot})$ depends in any way on either
$\mu$ or $A_i$.  If your answer is No, (as I hope t will be) , then
$\sum_{j=1}^J (Y_{ij}- \overline Y_ {i \cdot})^2$ is pretty much like
a sum $\sum_{j=1}^J (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ where the $X_i$ are independent
$N(0,\sigma^2)$, right? And we know that the
distribution of the sum $\sum_{j=1}^J (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ is a *scaled*
$\chi^2$ distribution with the appropriate degrees of freedom (figure out
how many), don't we?
Finally, that outer sum is the sum of $I$ independent scaled $\chi^2$ distributions
with the same scale factor in each case, and so the double sum is
yet another scaled $\chi^2$ random variable with the same scale
factor as everybody else, and even more degrees of freedom (once again,
figure out how many).

S, there are no *unorthodox* techniques involving normal distributions
that you need to learn: it is all standard stuff. About the only thing
that might require some work is if you need to prove that 
$\sum_{j=1}^J (X_i - \bar{X})^2$ is a scaled $\chi^2$ random variable
on the grounds that the *definition* of a (scaled) $\chi^2$ random variable is the sum of the
squares of independent identically distributed normal random variables whereas the $(X_i - \bar{X})$ are *not* independent (though they
*are* identically distributed). But this too is a standard result;
see, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance).